How to retrieve strings from a localised string resource?
I have been trying to localise my stings by putting them int a resw file, but I cannot work out how to access them.
I am following the example as per "Localize strings in your UI and app package manifest" from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest
I am trying to set up multiple language paths as per the section "Factoring strings into multiple Resources Files" and have created a folder structure thus:

Of note here is the "Strings" folder with the en-GB and the About.resw file. My resw file is:

As per the example given, I should be able to use commands similar to:
var resourceLoader = Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("ErrorMessages");
this.myXAMLTextBlockElement.Text = resourceLoader.GetString("MismatchedPasswords");

So I replace "ErrorMessages" with "About" and "MismatchedPasswords" with "EULA" and I get this error...

I have looked all over, including various examples from stackoverflow, but I am obviously missing something. Any help would be appreciated!

You use the WinForms tag, though the link refers to UWP.

As per refered document you also need to add Resources.resw
"You only need to add /resources-file-name/ before the string resource identifier for Resources Files other than Resources.resw. That's because "Resources.resw" is the default file name, so that's what's assumed if you omit a file name"


Please add missing file and should be fine

Hi Zahid. That is a great suggestion, but I still cannot get it to work.

did you copy Name & Value columns in Resources.resw ?

I added another field and tested that as well.

@damichab i am confirming if you copied Let's say EULA in Resources.resw  also ?

No, I added a different field and changed the commands accordingly.
